# Multiply file uploads with one submit button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dropzone

I have 3 dropzones, each one accepts a different file. I want to have a submit button that will submit all the files that have been uploaded.

How do I write out that function?

I want it to have a handleSubmit function.

These are my state variables for the different files:

```
  const [csvFile, setCsvFile] = React.useState();
  const [emailFile, setEmailFile] = React.useState();
  const [domainFile, setDomainFile] = React.useState();

  const handleSubmit = async (file) => {
    const allFiles = [csvFile, emailFile, domainFile];
    setDisabled(true);
    if (!listId) {
      await Promise.all(
        allFiles.map((file_) => {
          console.log({ file });
          const formData = {
            name: _.get(file, 'meta.name', ''),
          };

          return dispatch(createListAction(formData))
            .then((response) => {
              const listIdentifier = _.get(response, 'data.id');
              uploadList({ csvFile, emailFile, domainFile }, listIdentifier);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              toast((t) => <Toast toastId={t} error={error} />, { duration: Infinity });
              console.log({ error });
            });
        }),
      );
    } else {
      allFiles.forEach((file_) => {
        uploadList(file, listId);
      });
    }
  };
```

At the moment when I press the submit button 3 files upload even though only 1 was uploaded, I am not sure why 3 are uploading? Any ideas?

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's not markdown syntax, just copy paste the code, mark it and press ctrl+k.

Comment: If possible can you create and  share code sandbox link of your issue? Thank You

Comment: It's also a good idea to include the error in the question.

Comment: You may need to use Process_Files API to do that I guess, not sure though, you can google it online if that API is helpful for the purpose you are looking for.